# How to dismiss a Alert Dialog in Mono for android correctly?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

In my application i have a Custom AlertView, which works quite good so far. I can open it the first time, do, what i want to do, and then close it. If i want to open it again, i'll get

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`

so, here some code:

```
public Class ReadingTab
{
    ...
    private AlertDialog AD;
    ...
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
         btnAdd.Click += delegate
         {
             if (IsNewTask)
             {
                 ...
                 AlertDialog.Builer adb = new AlertDialog.Builer(this);
                 ...
                 View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AlertDView15ET15TVvert, null);
                 adb.setView(view)
              }
              AD = adb.show();
         }
     }
 }
```

that would be the rough look of my code.
Inside of btnAdd are two more buttons, and within one of them (btnSafe) i do `AD.Dismiss()` to close the Alert dialoge, `adb.dispose()` hasn't done anything.
the first time works fine, but when i call it the secon time, the debugger holds at `AD = adb.show();` with the Exception mentioned above.

So what do i have to do, to remove the Dialoge from the parent? i can't find removeView() anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you are setting up an `AlertView` once and then using it in multiple places (especially if you are using the same `AlertView` across different Activities) then you should consider creating a static `AlertDialog` class that you can then call from all over the place, passing in the current context as a parameter each time you want to show it.  Then when a button is clicked you can simply dismiss the dialog and set the instance to null.  Here is a basic example:

```
internal static class CustomAlertDialog
{
    private static AlertDialog _instance;
    private const string CANCEL = @"Cancel";
    private const string OK = @"OK";
    private static EventHandler _handler;

    // Static method that creates your dialog instance with the given title, message, and context
    public static void Show(string title,
        string message,
        Context context)
    {
        if (_instance != null)
        {
            throw new Exception(@"Cannot have more than one confirmation dialog at once.");
        }

        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.SetMessage(message);

        // Set buttons and handle clicks
        builder.SetPositiveButton(OK, delegate { /* some action here */ });
        builder.SetNegativeButton(CANCEL, delegate { /* some action here */});

        // Create a dialog from the builder and show it
        _instance = builder.Create();
        _instance.SetCancelable(false);
        _instance.Show();
    }
}
```

And from your Activity you would call your CustomAlertDialog like this:

```
CustomAlertDialog.Show(@"This is my title", @"This is my message", this);
```

Comment: Note to myself: learn how to explain my problem... in this AlertDialog i have, there is "nothing else" than my own View, no title, no message, no positive/neutral/negative buttons... on this view there are two buttons, and i want one of them to behave like a positive/etc. buttons. it should do some stuff and then close the whole thing completely, what it it doesn't. all I've tried resulted in the Exception above.

Comment: that's odd, i've answered myself but its gone.... well, just to note, i found my fault, the Custom View should be initialised in the same scope as the aLertDialoge and not one above. my question was on the completely wrong way to solve this...

Comment: thanks for the clarification, and good to hear that you figured it out!